# Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Robotics Stack Exchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to speed up robotic arm?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1642/how-to-speed-up-robotic-arm)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Calculate position of differential drive robot](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/calculate-position-of-differential-drive-robot)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to protect the milk in a homemade vending machine?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1660/how-to-protect-the-milk-in-a-homemade-vending-machine)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Moldable rubber for "feet"](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/moldable-rubber-for-feet)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Help with PID "units" in a quadcopter control system](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/help-with-pid-units-in-a-quadcopter-control-system)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What is the difference between RC motors for cars and helicopters?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/what-is-the-difference-between-rc-motors-for-cars-and-helicopters)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Design Calculations & Mathematical Modeling of Tricopters](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/design-calculations-mathematical-modeling-of-tricopters)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Any globally unique signature in Ardupilot hardware, or Arduino in general?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1755/any-globally-unique-signature-in-ardupilot-hardware-or-arduino-in-general)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Smooth servo movement for a crawling robot](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1678/smooth-servo-movement-for-a-crawling-robot)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Wind force impact on torque mechanical arm](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/wind-force-impact-on-torque-mechanical-arm)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)